# Git checkout with tabs commit with spaces

Tags: git, vim, spaces

I have a vim plugin that draws indentation lines similar to Sublime Text, but it requires whitespace to be represented as tabs. Complicating things, ideologically, I think spaces are preferable for the repository.

So, right now, I'm using vim to convert spaces to tab on write, which is computationally expensive and has started to slow down editing.

Is it possible for git to convert spaces to tabs on checkout/pull/merge and convert from tabs to spaces pre-commit?

Thanks

Comment: Tools are tools, don't let them dictate your workflow. Especially in the name of eye candy. Also, [vim-indent-guides](https://github.com/nathanaelkane/vim-indent-guides) supports both tabs and spaces.

Comment: Your files must be very large, or your computer very slow to have a simple global substitution "slow down editing" (rather, opening and writing, isn't it?!) Do you really think a Git / external solution is that much faster? Have you actually reduced the performance problem to the substitution? (which you do how?)

Comment: Linux usually has two utilities expressly for this purpose - called `expand` and `unexpand`...

Comment: @romainl I don't particularly like vim-indent-guides implementation, but forking it is an interesting thought.

Comment: @IngoKarkat The word editing is meaningless unless it encompasses opening & writing. The git solution, even if it was just as slow would only be run once per commit instead of every time I write the file and I know that's the cause because I can watch the replace work it's way down the file, replacing all tabs with spaces, saving and then replacing all spaces with tabs. I appreciate the quick response, but it seems to me like you just asked a lot of questions you thought you knew the answers to.

Comment: Again, you should have included your conversion implementation, because a `:substitute` doesn't behave the "I can watch it work" way you describe; i.e. there are no interim screen updates.

Answer (score 4):

You could do it using `.gitattributes`, see the [smudge/clean concept in the git book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes#Keyword-Expansion). You can create filters that convert the files on commit and checkout.

In `.gitattributes`, configure what files should be affected by your filter

```
* filter=spacetabs
```

On command line, tell what scripts should be run for filtering the files:

```
$ git config --global filter.spacetabs.clean tabs-to-spaces-script
$ git config --global filter.spacetabs.smudge spaces-to-tabs-script
```

Another possibility could be [git hooks](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks). Add conversion scripts that run on commit and checkout. But `.gitattributes` are probably more appropriate for this scenario.

Comment: .gitattributes was my first thought, but there's no way to define one filter for commits and another for pulls, is there?

Comment: @seagoj one filter maps to to two different scripts tabs-to-spaces-script and spaces-to-tabs-script.

Comment: @seagoj if you are asking for a filter to run on pull rather than checkout, that is not really necessary. You only care what the file looks like once you have checked it out.